# Android string resource storage outside of ...\res\values\strings.xml

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-resources

I'm making a program for Android using opengl es and I'd like to organize my project by keeping my glsl shader code as separate source files along with the java source code.

I realized, however, that for Android I need to store these as string resources, which are usually stored and managed in the `strings.xml` resource file, but I would very much like to keep them separate.

Any pointers on how to do this without directly embedding various glsl shader codes into `...\main\res\values\strings.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with Android Studio, there is even .glsl support for editing shaders. Just create a file and add .glsl as the extension, Android Studio will offer you to download a plugin for editing shaders. You can only place your shaders in your res/raw folder.

Comment: "You can only place your shaders in your res/raw folder." Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a java constants file and put all strings in that but it is not recommended.

Comment: Do you mean something like a a `StringConstants.java` file with a bunch of? I could certainly do that, but then it gets back to the problem of not keeping the glsl shader codes separate.

Comment: there are only two ways of doing it. No other tech feasibility.